# Adding a sequence to every row of a column in R?

Tags: r, join, data.table

I have two tables that I would like to combine in a certain way, however I have so far been unable to find a way as to how I should tackle this (I would say relatively easy?) problem.

The situation can be simplified as follows:

```
dt1:
1
2
3

dt2:
A
B
C
D
```

My goal:

```
dt12:
1 A
1 B
1 C
1 D
2 A
2 B
2 C
2 D
3 A
3 B
3 C
3 D
```

I tried different things but I am starting to feel like I am overlooking something very basic.

Comment: What you are looking for is a full outer join.

Comment: If these are just vectors rather than data.frames, you could use `expand.grid`

Comment: The jargon is cross join. If you google cross join r data.tables, you should find a few resources to do this